# Can't Access Rails Server on EC2 Instance from Public IP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, amazon-ec2

I have rails running on an Amazon EC2 instance but I'm having trouble accessing my rails server (port 3000) from public IPs. This was working as recently as last week but today when I started up my rails server I was unable to get a response from an outside IP. Even when I created a brand new rails project I was not able to access the server once I had started it.

Despite this I can access the Apache server by going through port 80. Moreover SSL continues to work.

I have already

- ensured that the port 3000 is open on my security group in the Amazon EC2 console
- checked my iptables on the Amazon instance. There are no rules and the default for the INPUT chain is to accept packets.
- banged my head against a wall.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify the port 3000 is opened **for every IPs addresses** and not only for your workplace's IP?

Also, your Amazon EC2 virtual machine's IP could have changed.